# Self modifying vector of std::function segfault

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-function

I'm trying to define a vector of function. When the functions are called they can add or remove items from the vector.

Ultra simplified it's something like the code below.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using F = std::function<void()>;
    std::vector<F> v;
    v.push_back([&v]{
        puts("v0");
        v.push_back([]{puts("v1");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v2");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v3");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v4");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v4");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v5");});
        v.push_back([]{puts("v6");});
    });
    v[0]();
}
```

The code compiles fine, but when run it segfault when calling the V0 function.

```
$ v0
$ Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

I understand the problem is related to vector reallocation (because if I add a `v.reserve(10);` before calling V0 it works fine), but I still don't understand what is wrong with that code and why it doesn't/shouldn't work.

Comment: It's basically an elaborate version of `class C { void f() { delete this; DoSomethingMore(); };`

Comment: As a workaround, you can invoke a copy of `v[0]`: `F{v[0]}();`.

Comment: Invoking a copy of v[0] could actually work in my real life use case, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I still don't understand what is wrong with that code and why it doesn't/shouldn't work.

When the vector reallocates, the objects stored inside it are destroyed after having been copied.

So, lambda that is being executed has been destroyed, and when you attempt to access the captured reference `v` of the destroyed lambda, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

If the move constructor of `std::function` was noexcept (and it will be in C++20), vector would move the elements instead, in which case the lambda would remain intact.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is there a way to make vector moving std::functions to the new allocated space instead of copying/destroying them ?

Comment: @kriss Wait for C++20, in which `std::function` becomes noexcept movable. Then vector will move it, and the lambda should stay intact.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the explanation. While I can understand, that the lambda at `v[0]` is destroyed while it is executed due to the reallocation, the relation to `v` is not clear to me. `v` refers to `std::vector<F>` so that reference should still be intact? (`[…]and when you attempt to access the captured reference v of the destroyed lambda[…]`)

Comment: @t.niese The reference is stored in the lambda. The reference will not be intact if the lambda is destroyed. Even though the referred object remains intact. Same as if you try to access an object through a reference member of a destroyed class object.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry now I get it.